# Convert date in momentJs to "YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss[+HHMM|-HHMM]."

Tags: reactjs, momentjs

How to convert date in momentJs to "YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss[+HHMM|-HHMM]."?

Please help!!!

I didn't find in momentJs needed format

UPD: I found the solution. If you need to get format with own UTC format you can use this:

```
const date = "2022-08-19";
const dateMomentFormatToISOString = "YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ";
moment(new Date(date)).format(dateMomentFormatToISOString);

The output will be:

2023-01-22T12:00:00+06:00
```

Comment: If you want to post an answer to your own question, please put it in the answers section rather than editing the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean `toISOString()`?

```js
console.log(new Date().toISOString())
```